# Whether browser recognize document HTML version

Tags: html, google-chrome, html4

I have a html document written in HTML 4. I used **required** attribute from HTML 5 which worked properly to my surprise. I saw error red border when input was empty.
I think that browser recognized this document as HTML 5 document and ignored DOCTYPE. 
My question is, how browser like Google Chrome recognize html document version.

Thanks for the hints.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        input:invalid {
            border: 2px dashed red;
        }

        input:valid {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use HTML5 elements with old HTML4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516803/is-it-possible-to-use-html5-elements-with-old-html4)

Answer (score 1):

> how browser like Google Chrome recognize html document version

They don't. They just parse HTML.

(The exception being [Doctype Switching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode), which uses the Doctype, but only to switch between "Good" and "1990s" behaviour, not to detect the version.)

Answer (score -1):

Using doctype

> The  declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to
>   the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

for more information https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: " it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in." It really isn't. The browser doesn't care what version of HTML the page is written in. Any more than it cares which version of CSS or JavaScript you think you're using. See Quentin's answer. And it's as good an example as any of why you should doubt everything you read on w3schools.